# Is it possible to make a homemade every function in JavaScript incorporating reduce?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Have some homework from a bootcamp where we are asked to incorporate our homemade reduce function in our homemade every function.

This is our homemade reduce

```
function reduce(arr, startingValue, func) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
        var currentVal = startingValue,
            l = arr.length,
            i = 0;
        for (; i < l; i++) {
            currentVal = func(currentVal, arr[i]);
        }
        return currentVal;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am puzzled as this is how the actual [every function is documented on MDN...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

> The every method executes the provided callback function once for each
>   element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns
>   a falsy value. If such an element is found, the every method
>   immediately returns false. Otherwise, if callback returns a truthy
>   value for all elements, every returns true. callback is invoked only
>   for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked
>   for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned
>   values.

To me when I think of reduce I can't see how or why you'd shoehorn reduce in an implementation of `every`.

Reduce starts with an accumulator which you build on while every essentially loops through an array applying a function (with a condition) and if one doesn't pass you get back false, otherwise true...

```
function every(arr, fnc) {
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (!(fnc(arr[i]))) {
         return false;
         break;
      }   
   }
  return true;
}
```

So how would you incorporate homemade reduce in a homemade every function?

**UPDATE**

Including context; while I thought I was as clear as [transparent aluminum](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Transparent_aluminum), on second thought I think I may not have been...

```
//These next two are very tricky!
//The functions every and any **should use your reduce function**
//to combine the collections into a true or false value.

describe("the function every", function() {

  //every asks 'does every element in this array pass the test given by the provided function?'
  //If so, every should return true, otherwise false.
  beforeEach(function() {
    spyOn(Array.prototype, 'every').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(window, 'reduce').and.callThrough();
  });

  var isEven = function(num) {
    return num % 2 === 0;
  };

  var getValue = function(i) {
    return i;
  };

  it("should handle an empty set", function() {
    //This gives a hint as to what your initial value for reduce should be...
    expect(every([], getValue)).toEqual(true);
  });

  it("should handle a set that contains even numbers", function() {
    expect(every([0, 10, 28], isEven)).toEqual(true);
  });

  it("should handle a set that contains an odd number", function() {
    expect(every([0, 11, 28], isEven)).toEqual(false);
  });

  it('should not use Array.prototype.every', function () {
    every([1,2,3], isEven);
    expect(Array.prototype.every.calls.any()).toEqual(false)
  });

  it('should re-use the reduce function created in previous specs', function(){
    every([0, 10, 28], isEven)
    expect(reduce).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Also another funny thing to add (besides the previous link), all the tests pass save the one where it asks to reuse reduce (of course)!

Comment: Is is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. what is the purpose of combining them? What is the context of the combination? What is the input? What is the expected output?

Comment: Thought it was as clear as one can be. Why would you use `reduce` in `creating` a every function.

Comment: You're implementation of `every` is ok and it's better than the one using `reduce`. But I think that it is just an exercice so you can understand `reduce` better. And I think you are clear as transparent alluminum :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`every` has to call the callback on every element and accumulates their return value (which will be a boolean) using the `AND` (`&&`) operator:

```
function every(arr, func) {
    return reduce(arr, true, function(test, e) {
        return test && func(e);
    });
}
```

we pass the initial value `true`, then we call `func` on each element of the array, and do a `AND` test with our accumulated `test`. `every` does this:

```
true && func(arr[0]) && func(arr[1]) && ... && func(arr[arr.length - 1])
```

if at least one call to `func` returned `false` then the whole test will be `false` (not every element passed the test `func`).

if all calls to `func` returned `true` then the whole test will be `true` (every element passed the test `func`).

**Note:** normally `every` should terminates on the first `false` value if any (like in your example). But you asked to implement it using `reduce`which will call `func` on all elements regardless of wether one returned `false` or not.

Comment: Thanks ibrahim for your example, its really helpful—so there IS an accumulation happening in the real `every`?

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz I don't think so. I think the implementation of standard `every` is exactly like yours (except that it passes the index and array as parameters to the callback and it's in the prototype of `Array` of course).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const every = (array, test) => array.reduce((acc, curr) => acc && test(curr), true)

const isEven = n => n % 2 === 0

console.log(every([2, 4, 6], isEven))

console.log(every([2, 3, 6], isEven))
```